# how can i pass url id parameter to javascript in mvc2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, url-parameters

Anyone knows how to pass an id parameter to jquery. For instance I have a url:
http://localhost:52271/News/Index/1

What I want is id parameter which is 1, in the above url. and I need to pass that id to the script like
var = url

where url should be the parameter which in this case 1,

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Where do you get this url from? Can't you use the Routes to fetch this value directly instead of having javascript code to parse it?

Comment: I am running a jquery accordion menu , I need the id value to make certain index of accordion menu active according to newsID. Well the url is presently on my local machine and is set up through the usercontrol which is : <%: Html.ActionLink(ApexTrackDays.Tools.TruncateString(item.Title, 24, ApexTrackDays.TruncateOptions.None), "Index","News", new {id = item.ID},null)%>

Comment: ideally the url will be like http://www.apextrackdays.co.uk/News/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information on URI manipulation in Javascript: [link](http://www.suite101.com/content/how-to-get-url-parts-in-javascript-a48335)

That said, try this:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var id = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
```

**EDIT:**

Verify that you really have the URL:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
alert(url); //verify
var pathArray = url.split( '/' );
var id = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];
```

Comment: yeh i m getting this url: /news/index/2

Comment: what i want to do pass this id value to accordion: $("#accordion").accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                autoHeight: false,
                active: id
            });

Comment: ohh thnx i sorted out , it was returning string , i converted it to int using parseint(id) .. cheeers

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I assume you're trying to assign the id from the current url to a Javascript variable. You can parse the id out of the `window.location.href` property like this:

```
var segments = window.location.href.split('/');
var id = segments[segments.length - 1];
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with this approach?

Comment: what i want to do pass this id value to accordion: $("#accordion").accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false, active: id });